# RXJS avoid repeating call if request is on progress

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a config data in project which is used by multiple components and services.
The idea is to build a service which gets just once the data from API and provides it cached every time is needed.

```js
private getConfig(): Observable<InitConfig> {
  return this.http.get('public/config/initconfig')
    .pipe(
      tap((config: InitConfig) => {
        this.config = config; // set the config
      }),
    );
}


public getInitConfig(): Observable<InitConfig> {
  if ( _.isEmpty(this.config) ) {
    return this.getConfig();
  } else {
    return of(this.config);
  }
}
```

The problem is when the get request is on progress and the data is not cached yet. If another consumer calls getInitConfig() at this time I get duplicated get request.

Answer (score 4):

You need a private observable that indicates if the config was already fetched, if it wasn't (which means it's the first subscription) initialize it and either way return it.

First, add a `private config$: Observable<InitConfig>` to your service.
Next, use `shareReplay(1)` in order to share the result among the subscribers.

It should look something like this:

```js
  private config$: Observable<InitConfig>;

  getInitConfig(): Observable<InitConfig> {
    if (!this.config$) {
      this.config$ = this.http
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
        .pipe(
          tap(() => console.log("config fetched")),
          shareReplay(1)
        );
    }

    return this.config$;
  }
```

You can test it by subscribing multiple times and see `config fetched` being logged only once:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configService.getInitConfig().subscribe(() => console.log('Config Subscription - 1'))
    this.configService.getInitConfig().subscribe(() => console.log('Config Subscription - 2'))
    this.configService.getInitConfig().subscribe(() => console.log('Config Subscription - 3'))
  }
```

You can see the full code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mjjoey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

The usual problem with your approach is, whenever you make an HTTP call, its going to give you a **new observable**. This new observable is **by default** **COLD** in nature . It means you have to subscribe to it to get the result.
If you call it multiple times, you are gonna get multiple observables and you will end up making multiple HTTP requests.

**SOLUTION**

You should use a **single Observable** and **subscribe** to it multiple times with **Share** operator. **Share** operator will make the observable **HOT** after making the first HTTP call. As soon as it becomes hot, if other subscriber is found, rather than making an other HTTP call, it will simply return the data.

in service,

```
private publicObservable = this.getConfig();          // publicObservable single observable  

private getConfig(): Observable<InitConfig> {
  return this.http.get('public/config/initconfig')
    .pipe(
        share()                                      // share operator
    );
}


public getInitConfig(): Observable<InitConfig> {
     return this.service.publicObservable;
}
```

In Demo, I subscribe to same HTTP 8 times. If I remove, **share** operator, you can see in **NETWORK tab**, 8 calls will be made

With **share** operator, only 1 request will be made.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-rxjs-operator-live-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

I hope this will help !

Comment: In general you answer is correct. But i try to explain why `shareReplay(1)` better suits here. In your example the 8 subscribers only share the same value if the subscriptions are made before or while the async operation is running. If you subscribe later to your service the same data is requested again. You can see this in the network-tab of your modified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-rxjs-operator-live-example-kgpudy
Thats why i recommand `shareReplay(1)` for this. Its also makes the oberservable hot and additionally provide the last emitted value to new subscribers.

Comment: Yes @enno.void. I completely agreed ! No doubt about it.

Comment: I tried this but I still have lots of duplicated HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

promises will work exactly as you want. it is the most easy and elegant way

```
private getConfig(): Promise<InitConfig> {
  return this.http.get('public/config/initconfig').toPromise();
}


public getInitConfig(): Promise<InitConfig> {
  return this.config = this.config || this.getConfig();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this solution? Apart from changing the `getInitConfig` method signature?

Comment: The problem is turning Observables into Promises. All you're doing is removing functionality. Everything the OP wants can be achieved with Observables, and the Observable approach also allows for better maintainability and modularity in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach which looks a little bit like a Redux state management system.

```js
private loading = false;
private loaded = false;
private config$ = new BehaviorSubject<InitConfig>(null);

public getConfig() {
  this.requestConfig();
  return this.config$.asObservable();
}

public requestConfig() {
  if (loading || loaded) {
    return;
  }
  this.loading = true;
  this.http.get('public/config/initconfig')
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((config: InitConfig) => {
        this.config$.next(config);
        this.loaded = true;
        this.loading = false;
      }),
    ).subscribe();
}
```

It may be worth looking into implementing something like NgRx, as it is built precisely for this kind of more complex state management.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `shareReplay(1)`

```
private getConfig(): Observable<InitConfig> {
  return this.http.get('public/config/initconfig')
    .pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
}
```

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2osdk

Comment: tried to add the shareReplay(1) operator and i still have repeating requests.

Comment: @sandum there must be another error on your side. Here a demo to proof that its working as i said:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2osdk

The http call is done only once!

Comment: I can't get it to work either.